# how to - image slider

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

hello every one
i want to make a nice slider of images,
there is ant build ed class that support that?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be to store an array of Images and then use a UISlider with that. Connect the value changed outlet of UISlider to this method in IB.

```
-(IBAction)valueChanged: (id) sender{
    UISlider *tempSlider = (UISlider *) sender;
    imageView.image = [arrayOfImages objectAtIndex: tempSlider.value];
```

}

(where imageView is your UIImageView and arrayOfImages is a NSArray where you store images.

or something like that. i just free typed this and i'm sure there're better ways to do this too.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) and in it add [UIImageView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s as subviews.